# Edubuntu in Ubuntu

Tags: software-center, software-installation, edubuntu

Guys I'm currently using Ubuntu LTS Version 12.04.4.

I would like to install Edubuntu with higher secondary that is pre-college(age 16) and college level packages installed.

I would like to know how to go installing Edubuntu should I download the ISO or is there a easy way I install from within Ubuntu? If from within Ubuntu how do I do it? From the software centre or?

Please be detailed in your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for not fully understanding the meaning of higher secondary as our system is different :)

but you can do it simply from Software centre by installing (Educational Desktop for Ubuntu)

sure you can select only what you need to minimize download size as it includes The complete educational desktop (preschool, primary, secondary, and tertiary +others)